# Disprove uniform convergence of $x^n$ where $ x\in[0,1)$

Tags: uniform-convergence

So I'm looking at $f_n(x)=x^n ~~~x\in[0,1)$. It is obvious that it converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$.
Is it now possible to disprove uniform convergence using the Uniform norm? This would mean I have to show $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||f-f_n||\neq0\qquad\text{and as }f=0\qquad\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||f_n||_D\neq0$$
With the definition of the Uniform norm:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup\{x^n:x\in[0,1)\}\neq0$$
But isn't this false as $x^n$ converges to $0$ in this interval?

Or do I just misunderstood supremum, and it is actually meant the lowest value that is not reached, which would be $1$ (or at least $\neq0$?) and then everything would work out as $1\neq0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supremum is the lowest upper bound. Clearly $1$ is an upper bound of $\{x^n\mid x\in[0,1)\}$ and it's the least upper bound because $x^n\to1$ as $x$ goes to $1$. It does not have to be attained, but $x^n$ always reaches values arbitrarily close to $1$ on the interval $[0,1)$.

I suggest you look at the graph of $x^n$ for high $n$ on [WolflamAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5+from+0+to+1).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$
\sup\{ x^n : x\in[0,1)\} = 1 
$$
because for $r>0$,
$$
\left(1-\frac rn\right)^n \ge 1-r
$$
(the [Bernoulli inequality](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/In%C3%A9galit%C3%A9_de_Bernoulli))

Comment: Ok, so I realy did misunderstand supremum and the value which is not reached is actually meant. The one I described is the maximum then?

Comment: the $\sup $ is the lowest value bigger than all the values. here I proved that it is always $>1-r$ for any $r$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^n=\frac{1}{e}$ which contradicts uniform convergence.

Comment: Downvoter, please improve the post!

Comment: Maybe you could explain more how that leads to a contradiction. That is a good argument I upvoted it, but it might not be transparent to everyone what is happening.